# Cannot resolve symbol HttpGet,HttpClient,HttpResponce in Android Studio 1.5

Tags: android

I just copy a class JSONParser in my app. It gives an error :  Cannot resolve symbol HttpGet,HttpClient,HttpResponse.
  Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
  useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.chifco.pfe.myapplication"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
  }
  buildTypes {
     release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
  }

dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

Comment: try to comment those classes & build project, then uncomment and check imports

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClient` is not supported any more in [Android 6.0 (API level 23)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client). You have to use `URLConnection` or downgrade to SDK 22 (compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'`)

If you need SDK 23, add this to your gradle:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpClient` is deprecated and now not supported. You can use [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) instead.